# How do I use the CA3306E ADC with Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi

I have successfully run the MCP3008 ADC with both the Arduino and the Raspberry Pi, however, this ADC seems to be way beyond me. The connections are not the simple SPI ones as they were in the MCP3008. In the datasheet too, it mentions the connections, but it has an external comparator, I believe, to get it to work and there is no code (obviously). Every example code that I found online for this ADC uses Linux Kernel Module, and none of those codes are complete that I can copy and paste it to test and then make changes accordingly. How can I get this ADC to run?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the CA3306 instead of a newer part in the 10-15MSPS range?

Comment: Is there a newer part in the 10-15 MSPS? This was the ADC I could find with that range